# How do I get the pixel color under the cursor?

Tags: visual-c++, gdi+, screen, pixel

I need a fast command line app to return the color of the pixel under the mouse cursor.

How can I build this in VC++, I need something similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1483928/how-to-read-the-color-of-a-screen-pixel/1483963#1483963), but ideally not in .NET so it can be run many times per second?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Off the top of my head, the straightforward way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Windows.h>

int main(void) {
    POINT p;
    COLORREF color;
    HDC hDC;
    BOOL b;

    // Get the device context for the screen
    hDC = GetDC(NULL);
    if (hDC == NULL)
        return 3;

    // Get the current cursor position
    b = GetCursorPos(&p);
    if (!b)
        return 2;

    // Retrieve the color at that position
    color = GetPixel(hDC, p.x, p.y);
    if (color == CLR_INVALID)
        return 1;

    // Release the device context again
    ReleaseDC(GetDesktopWindow(), hDC);

    printf("%i %i %i", GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color));
    return 0;
}
```

**ETA:** Appears to work, at least for me.

**ETA2:** Added some error checking

**ETA3:** Commented code, compiled executable and a Visual Studio Solution can be found in [my SVN repository](http://svn.lando.us/joey/Public/SO/3078919).

Comment: Thank you so much! I suppose I build this in a "Win32 Console App"??

Comment: @Jeremy: Yes. I couldn't figure out how to build it from the command line but as a console application from Visual Studio it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks! Just one more thing, I'm trying to invoke this behind-the-scenes from another App, so is there a way to hide the black commandline window from showing?

Comment: I'm finding some answers here .. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763669/how-to-hide-a-console-application-in-c .. but do you know a quick way to do the same? I basically need to return some values without showing the console window.

Comment: Pretty much every language/environment has a facility of running a console program and retrieving its output. Use what's applicable for you. I have no idea what programming language you want to run it from. For plain Windows API you can use `CreateProcess`, in C# use `Process.Start`, in C you can use `popen`, &c. ...