# How to get pixel color under cursor?

Tags: rust, colors, window, pixel

I am looking for a way to get the pixel color value under the cursor.

This of course working from any window, not just a 'rust-owned' window like a winit window.

I found a few [library of window capture](https://github.com/bryal/captrs) and [solution in other language](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3078919/how-do-i-get-the-pixel-color-under-the-cursor) , but nothing that fullfil my need.

Comment: Which operating systems do you want to support?

Comment: I was aiming for all personal computer OS

but I would already be happy with Linux Debian based

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple cross-platform solution using [autopilot](https://crates.io/crates/autopilot).

First get the cursor position using [`mouse::location()`](https://docs.rs/autopilot/latest/autopilot/mouse/fn.location.html) and then use that position to grab the pixel on the screen using [`screen::get_color(position)`](https://docs.rs/autopilot/latest/autopilot/screen/fn.get_color.html).

A full sample:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mouse_location = autopilot::mouse::location();
    let pixel = autopilot::screen::get_color(mouse_location).unwrap();
    println!(
        "Pixel color under cursor (RGBA): {},{},{},{}",
        pixel.0[0], pixel.0[1], pixel.0[2], pixel.0[3]
    )
}
```

Comment: the alpha value is not supposed to always be 1.0?

Comment: Yes, you are probably right, because in the docs it is stated, that this returns the  RGB color...