# How to run a console application on system Startup , without appearing it on display(background process)?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, c#-4.0

I want to run a console application on system start up without appearing it on display screen means i want to run a application as a background process.How to do this?

Comment: Combine: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/674628/how-do-i-set-a-program-to-launch-at-startup and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2763669/how-to-hide-a-console-application-in-c-sharp or alternatively http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/csharpgeneral/thread/ea8b0fd5-a660-46f9-9dcb-d525cc22dcbd.

Comment: you can use Windows service

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can change the output type in project properties as console Application type to Windows application type and compile it, Then it won't display any window at start up.

Answer (score 5):

**In short:** The simplest way might be to **schedule task** to be started from your operating system. This might be the way easiest thing to set.

You may easily run it in the background with the scheduler - [How to run a .Net Console App in the background](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2686289/1437962)

Answer (score 0):

Try this to hide the console window and run in background

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
private static extern int ShowWindow(int Handle, int showState);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
public static extern int GetConsoleWindow();


public static void HideWindow()
{
    int win = GetConsoleWindow();
    ShowWindow(win, 0);
}
```

why dont you try windows service ?  windows service runs the process in background.