# how to continuously run a c# console application in background

Tags: c#

I would like to know how to run a c# program in background every five minute increments. The code below is not what I would like to run as a background process but would like to find out the best possible method to do this using this code so that I can implement it on another code. so this process should run after a five minute increment. I know I could use threads to do so, but dont really now how to implement this. I know this is the best way [How to run a console application on system Startup , without appearing it on display(background process)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133053/how-to-run-a-console-application-on-system-startup-without-appearing-it-on-dis) this to run in the background, but how would I have the code running in five minute increments

```
 class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Write("hellow world");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Comment: If there is no output in the application, you should consider creating a service instead.

Comment: If there is no output in the application, why you wrote `Console.Write` ?

Comment: is this is same question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2686289/how-to-run-a-net-console-app-in-the-background

Comment: or use windows schedule to run it every 5 min

Comment: Make windows service using TopShelf and then in While(true) scope put Thread.Sleep(5*60*1000)

Comment: Do you want to write a program that is doing something every 5 minutes? Or do you have a program where you don't have source code access and which you want to start every 5 minutes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Why not just use [Windows Task Scheduler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383614%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)?

Set it to run your app at the desired interval. It's perfect for this sort of job and you don't have to mess about with forcing threads to sleep which can create more problems that it solves.

Answer (score 10):

This app should run continuously, putting out a message every 5 minutes.
Isn't that what you want?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        while (true) {
            Console.Write("hellow world");
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000 * 60 * 5); // Sleep for 5 minutes
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: @Cemafor He edited the answer after my comment. His initial code would run regardless of an interval. I have deleted it since it is no longer relevant

Comment: why would you need a while

Comment: The `while(true)` will cause the loop to run forever or until you terminate the app..

Comment: while true is needed to don't let the app reach the end.

Comment: yeah.. but that whill sleep for five minutes not run every five minutes

Comment: The `Console.Write` will be run every 5 minutes.  Replace that line with whatever other code/function you want to run every 5 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

How about using a [System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer.aspx)?

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 5, 0); // sets it to 5 minutes
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.Start();
    }

    static void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // whatever you want to happen every 5 minutes
    }

}
```

Comment: You just need to prevent closing of the console app here.

Comment: put a `Console.ReadLine()` at the end and it will keep running.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest way to "fire" a new process every X minutes is to use [Windows Task Scheduler](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4250516/533120).

You could of course do something similar programmatically, e.g. create your own service, that starts the console application every X minutes.

---

All this under assumption you actually want to close the application before the next iteration. Alternatively, you might just keep it active the whole time. You might use [one of the timer classes](https://stackoverflow.com/a/186086/533120) to fire events periodically, or even a `Thread.Sleep` in a very simplified scenario....