# Running Metro Apps Minimized from a C# Application

Tags: c#, process, windows-10-universal

For non-metro apps, the `ProcessStartInfo.WindowStyle` can be used to run the app minimized:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("notepad.exe");
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

It is also possible using [Kernel32.CreateProcess](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44191519/7050782).

However, for metro apps, the Window Style approach does not work:

```
ProcessStartInfo processStartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("microsoft-edge://");
processStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Minimized;
Process.Start(processStartInfo);
```

and CreateProcess is [only applicable for non-metro apps](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/861d6849-d5d5-4b2e-b5cd-6157286a9104/launch-external-program-from-metro-style-app?forum=winappswithcsharp).

Is there a way to run metro apps minimized? (Note that this is different from running the metro app, getting the window handle, then minimizing the window)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, it seems like minimize the UWP app into the system tray currently is not supported. If you do want this feature, you may help that happen by voting [UWP System tray support.](https://wpdev.uservoice.com/forums/110705-universal-windows-platform/suggestions/12817866-uwp-system-tray-support)